# PHP - how to select?

Tags: php, html, cross-domain, selector, domparser

So i get content from another side using simple html dom parser. The sites structure looks like this:

```
<div class="content">
   <p> Text i dont need </p>
   <a href="#top">Anchor I dont need</a>
   <h3>Heading I need</h3>
   <p>Text I need</p>
</div>
```

So you see they don't have classes and the text inside h3 and p is variable in length and content and also the place of h3 can change from site to site, because sometimes there are more p tags before the h3.
How could I do this?

Website: http://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/DE/Laenderinformationen/00-SiHi/BolivienSicherheit.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use DomManipulating PHP class, like : http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/
Then you can use :

```
$html->find('div', 1)->class = 'bar';
```

Or you can simply user Jquery to add your classes / attributes.

```
$('.content').find('p').addClass('bar');
```

Comment: If i would use your method all the <p> tags would get a class, but I only need the first one under the first <h3>. Other ideas?

Comment: Please learn how to manipulate DOM. With jquery you can use p.last-child, and with PHP, the 1 in find method is your element index.